# Laravel login from sqlite DB, getting "PDOException could not find driver"

Tags: forms, sqlite, laravel, authentication

I am trying to write a simple login form using Laravel and sqlite DB on localhost (vagrant and virtualbox). However, after entering username and passoword I keep getting "PDOException could not find driver" error. Any ideas?

--- EDIT ---

Had to install sqlite driver by typing

```
  sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

in my terminal window. It was somehow not enabled by default :/

Comment: Can you show us your `/app/config/auth.php` and `/app/config/database.php`? Don't forget to remove passwords ;)

Comment: What do you mean by removing passwords?

Comment: When you post your `database.php` don't show us your passwords.

Comment: It's on localhost and for acedemic activity only. No problem

Comment: @deividaspr You should add your solution as an answer. I would be the first to upvote it because it solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like your version of PHP is either missing, or has disabled, the PDO extension.  Use the `phpinfo` function to list out the extensions installed and enabled.  If PDO isn't there, look for a commented line in your `php.ini` file(s) and/or talk to the person maintaining your servers.

Comment: I have found that sqlite is not enabled by using phpinfo - "PDO drivers mysql". How should I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your system has missing php SQLite installation.

Install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
```