# Sqlite PDO Exception with laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I want to make a migration to database.sqlite, but i get the following error while trying to execute a migration:
[image]

```
     'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'database.sqlite'),
      DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
      REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
      REDIS_PASSWORD=null
      REDIS_PORT=6379
```

And the database.sqlite file has a text file type.
I am using ubuntu 16.04lts and phpstorm.

Comment: Try installing SQLite, `apt install php7.0-sqlite3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdo exception driver not found in laravel for sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949781/pdo-exception-driver-not-found-in-laravel-for-sqlite)

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question - [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949781/pdo-exception-driver-not-found-in-laravel-for-sqlite), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485331/laravel-login-from-sqlite-db-getting-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803728/pdo-sqlite-could-not-find-driver-php-file-not-processing) ...

Comment: I installed sqlite3 successfuly but it does not fix it, i am using php 7.1.8 though, i tried 7.1-sqlite3 but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you check if sqlite is enabled in your `php.ini` file ?

Comment: The problem is fixed, i was editing example.env not env file, and also 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'database.sqlite'), is wrong, instead i changed to: default' => database_path('database.sqlite'). But for some reason laravel creates the first one instead of the second. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed, i was editing example.env not the real env file, and also, on the database.php file, i had 
             'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'database.sqlite'), 
and changed it to: 
              default' => database_path('database.sqlite').
I just don't know why laravel sets it up as the first one.